# Ranking system using MySQLi and PHP (Multiple checks)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have this function setup to fetch user ranks

```
function rank($user) {
    $q = query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY level DESC");
    $rank = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        $rank++;
        if($row['username'] == $user) {
            return $rank;
        }
    }
}
```

*Please note: query() is a function that automatically queries the database.*

This is returning false, what I'm wanting is this:

```
username    level    money    exp    id
john        3        2        213    4
bob         3        132      23     5
mark        4        3423     2      6
```

I want it to sort based on level, but if two users(`john` and `bob`) have the same level, then resort to exp, then to money, then user ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give multiple expression in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY level DESC, exp DESC, money DESC, user_id DESC
```

Comment: query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY level DESC, money DESC, id DESC"); That query seems not to be working.

Comment: @PhilGibson You'll have to be a bit more specific than "not to be working"

Comment: @PhilGibson And you missed "exp DESC" in the `order by` clause.

Comment: He mentions that the `query` function returns false with his own query. It seems he has got some other issue.

Comment: On further inspection, I found an internal sql issue. The query function works fine. @Perumal93

Comment: Yeah. Your SQL query is all fine but you got an issue internally with your code or elsewhere.